# Is there CLI tool like `ls`, but which also shows extra information about directory (first line from README.md, for example)

Tags: command-line, ls

I often create small projects as separate directories in one big `~/code` directory. However, with time I forget what are those directories about, and unfortunately, `dirname` isn't good enough to decipher the use case.

Is there a way to augment `ls` (or alias to another utility) which will also show short info about each project? I envision it to show a few lines from README.md in the directory of a project alongside with dir name.

Comment: You have a tool-box. You should be able to do it in a two line shell script (3 if you include `#!/bin/bash`, in the count).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool; but this is UNIX, and so you can easily create one.    `:-)`

---

Not having any `README.md` files around, I'll use `.gitignore` instead, as the file under each subdirectory to print the first line from:

```bash
find . -type d -printf '%30f ==> ' -exec sed q {}/.gitignore \;
```

Sample output:

```
                   control-DBs ==> autogen.h
                         basic ==> flarp.exe
                    postgresql ==> libpgstore.a
                            ui ==> .DS_Store
                       plugins ==> *.*~
```

#### How it works

- `-type d` : We are looking for subdirectories only.
- `printf '%30f ==> '` : The `-printf` accepts a bunch of codes, for printing various information about the file (*technically speaking, a directory is a kind of file*) being processed.  There are enough codes to emulate output of `ls(1)` with the simpler options.  See `man find` or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html for the complete list; a few must-haves are

  - `%f`: basename
  - `%s`: size in bytes
  - `%m`: permission (a.k.a. mode bits)
- `-exec sed q {}/.gitignore \;` : Here we give `find(1)` a custom command to execute for each subdirectory being processed.

  - `{}` stands for the file's path
  - `sed q fff` is one way to print the first line of file "`fff`"
  - `\;` tells `find(1)` where the custom command ends.

#### What if only *some* subdirectories have `.gitignore` in them?

```bash
find . -type d -exec [ -e {}/.gitignore ] \; -printf '%30f ==> ' -exec sed q {}/.gitignore \;
```

We again turn to `-exec` for help.  Say the subdirectory being currently processed is called "`ddd`"; then `[ -e ddd/.gitignore ]` will evaluate to false if there is no `.gitignore` in `ddd/`.  As soon as a test evaluates to false, `find(1)` gives up and moves on to the next subdirectory.